# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException when accessing the application

Tags: java, swing, jboss

I have a swing application hosted using a `JBOSS` server running in a server. In my laptop I downloaded the `JNLP` of that remote application and started it successfully. I'm also able to interact with the application by clicking on the button etc.

Now I'm using a API called `Marathon` which is a wrapper of `Selenium webdriver` except that it's used for testing swing application. Now if I start the JNLP file using this Marathon API it starts fine. The problem is when I click on the `login` button using this Marathon API through it's driver I see thew following exception

```
7286     ERROR  [AWT-EventQueue-1]: Root cause: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

In the same session started by Marathon if I manually click on the `login` button it works fine. The problem appears to be happening only when I try to click on the button programatically using Marathon API.

I even tried passing

```
profile.addWSArgument("-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/ssl.keystore");
profile.addWSArgument("-J-Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
profile.addWSArgument("-J-Djava.naming.provider.url=10.66.87.0:7001");
```

Nothing works. Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your context, try this

```
System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
System.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:<port>");
```

or place jndi.properties is your project root directory.